# How to use total function in Laravel Shopping cart

Tags: php, laravel, shopping-cart

I'm using the shopping cart function in laravel, I have used the Cart :: add function successfully, but when using the Total function fails, the total amount is greater than the amount that I calculate.

Any suggestions? thanks!

This is my code MyController

```
public function muahang($id){
        $product_buy = DB::table('products')->where('id',$id)->first();
        Cart::add(array('id'=>$id,'name' =>$product_buy->name,'qty'=>1,'price'=>$product_buy->price,'options'=>array('img'=>$product_buy->image)));
        $content = Cart::content();
        return redirect()->route('giohang');
    }
    public function giohang(){
        $content = Cart::content();
        $total = Cart::total();
        return view('user.pages.shopping',compact('content','total'));
    }
```

**This is my view:**

```
@foreach($content as $content_item)
          <tr>
            <td class="image">
              <a href="#"><img title="product" alt="product" src="{{ asset('resources/upload/'.$content_item->options->img) }}" height="50" width="50"></a>
            </td>
            <td  class="name"><a href="#">{{ $content_item->name }}</a></td>
            <td class="quantity"><input type="text" size="1" value="{{ $content_item->qty }}" name="quantity[40]" class="span1"></td>
            <td class="total"> <a href="#"><img class="tooltip-test" data-original-title="Update" src="{!! asset('public/user/img/update.png') !!}" alt=""></a>
              <a href="#"><img class="tooltip-test" data-original-title="Remove"  src="{!! asset('public/user/img/remove.png') !!}" alt=""></a>
            </td>
            <td class="price">{{ number_format($content_item->price,0,',','.') }} </td>
            <td class="total">{{ number_format(($content_item->price * $content_item->qty),0,',','.') }} </td> 
          </tr>
          @endforeach
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="container">
      <div class="pull-right">
          <div class="span4 pull-right">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered ">
              <tr>
                <td><span class="extra bold totalamout">Total :</span></td>
                <td><span class="bold totalamout">{!! $total  !!}</span></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
            <input type="submit" value="CheckOut" class="btn btn-orange pull-right">
            <input type="submit" value="Continue Shopping" class="btn btn-orange pull-right mr10">
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: The total() method basically calculated total of all items in the cart, given there price and quantity.

Answer (score 0):

**Suggestion:**

As this is the problem of Cart Option. Third party package gloudemans can be used for Cart. This works nice with laravel.

All the proper information about  Installation and usages of  gloudemans are avabilable below

```
https://github.com/Crinsane/LaravelShoppingcart
```

Hopefully, it will be workable.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$total = Cart::total();
```

To

```
 $total = Cart::subtotal();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an this package?

[AvoRed E commerce](https://github.com/avored/framework)

Even inside your blade of view files you can simply do.

{{ Cart::total() }}

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sum()` method. The sum method returns the sum of all items in the collection: [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections#method-sum).

In your Cart Model

```
public function total()
{
    return $this->products->sum('price');
}
```

view.blade

```
Cart total: {{ $cart->total() }}
// Total: 150
```